# Change height of div using data from MYSQL database every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm developing a page which requires getting updated data from my database repeatedly.  For test purposes, I only have one div with a fixed height.
I can update the text in the div using the .load() method, however, I need to adjust the height of the div to the value of the data returned from my database.

I thank you in advance for your help!

```
<body>
<div id="status" >This is a TEST</div>

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#status').load('check_status.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000); // refresh every 5000 milliseconds
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What does `check_status.php` return ?

Comment: I am updating the database with the desired height in pixels.  The check_status.php returns the most recent update to the table.  It will always be data such as "123px", "235px", 67px", etc.  The height of the div needs to get higher or lower based on the most recent update to the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to  make your div `#status` fits its content

-->.Add in CSS :

```
#status{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

---

If your concern to set height proportional to content, you can do this :

```
function calculateHeight(dataSize){
   //i.e (0.7%)
   return dataSize*0.07;

};
$.get('check_status.php',function(data){
    let element=$('#status');
    element.css('height',calculateHeight(data.length)+'px');
    element.fadeIn('slow');
});
```